# Get user's geographical address

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to track user's location seamlessly without needing the user to enter his/her address?

// ASP.NET

Thanks

Comment: What if he is in a internet café or in the mountains surfing your site from his mobile? It is unlikely that this is his home address :-)

Comment: See following:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode37GeolocationGeotargetingReverseIPAddressLookupInASPNETMVCMadeEasy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) to guess their location from their IP address. Obviously, this is easily spoofed, but it's good enough for a substantial proportion of visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_geolocation) feature of HTML 5. Detecting the location of the client based on their IP address does not exactly gives you the exact info. A user could be using a VPN for example.

There is sample on how you can use this feature on the below post :

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NerdDinnerBeingUpdatedToMVC3WithRazorHTML5GeoLocationEFCodeFirstJQueryMobileYepNopeAndModernizrAndAFixedMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx